# Lack of an authentication prompt for secured URLs if requested through $.ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, authentication, cross-domain

When I work from home, URLs to our development servers require basic authentication. 
So, if a web page has a script or link tag reference to our development server, we get a prompt for each of those server URLs.

Recently, I wrote an ajax call to an API on the development server using jQuery `$.ajax`.  I do not get the authentication prompt, and Firebug reports 401 unauthorized.  However, if I put this API directly in the browser address bar, I get the prompt.

Currently, I have to switch to Chrome and invoke --disable-web-security.  When I do that, the `$.ajax` call will cause the browser to give me a prompt.

Is this a "problem" with `$.ajax()` or the browser or something else?

Comment: Solution already exists: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507234/how-to-use-basic-auth-and-jquery-and-ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could send your credentials along with the request as suggested in the docs of [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

```
$.ajax({
    // ...
    username: "foo",
    password: "bar"
});
```

make sure you're not pushing your personal credential to some SCM, though!